# How do I use PostCSS Auto Reset?

Tags: css, postcss

There seems to be no documentation and I don't quite understand the code examples on the [Github page](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset).

I assumed that it would automatically append reset rules to the output CSS file. The documentation uses things like `.block` but doesn't say what they're used for.

What does the following mean?

```
.block {
  padding: 1em;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.block__element {
  margin: 1em;
}

.block--modifier {
  border: 1em;
}
```

Is this just regular CSS? I've not seen `--modifier` before. If it is just regular CSS what is the purpose of this plugin because I can override defaults in a regular CSS file. I'm trying to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are talking about (`--` or `__`) is just a CSS methodology called BEM (Block - Element - Modifier) trying to keep CSS maintainable. There is no more hidden magic to it. Further info: http://getbem.com/

The mentioned `postcss-autoreset` plugin basically just adds the `all: initial;` property to selectors, which might already have some styles. Therefore you can be sure of no other styles conflicting with your CSS.

Comment: Ah I get it. So it only adds `all: initial;` to the elements you style? I was confused because I was loading an empty stylesheet in a document and noticing nothing was resetting. But, when I did `h1 { color: red; }` it reset it.

Comment: Yes, that's all. If your question is answered, feel free to close it / mark as answered.